# HTTP / HTTPS outbound requests blocked in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**TL;DR TCP traffic was blocked internally, that's why I couldn't do the requests at that time**

I'm having some troubles trying to make HTTP / HTTPS requests from a EC2 instance on AWS.

The instance public IP is working, and I can connect via SSH.

IT WORKS When I try to ping or nslookup a domain:

```
[root@my-instance etc]# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.15.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

BUT when I try to curl an url I've got this:

```
# curl -v https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.164.174...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e: Network is unreachable
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4004:803::200e...
...
```

I've got other instances associated to the same VPC and with the same outbound settings, this is the only one which blocks the outgoing requests.

Some details about the network:

Instance Security Group Outbound settings:
[image: Security group outbound settings]

The Subnet attached is also connected to an Internet Gateway:
[image: subnet route settings]

And these are the ACL traffic settings (which are the same ACL for other instances)
[image: ACL traffic settings]

This instance has an Elastic-IP associated and it's on a VPC (which other instances are also connected and the outbound traffic is OK),

I've tried to attach a new security group (a clone from the original) to that instance.

Does anyone has any ideas what's happening?

Comment: If other instances in the same subnet can do this then it's most likely a problem with the instance. Have you checked iptables?

Comment: Hi @Tim, iptables rules are all ACCEPT:

iptables -S

-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Comment: Note also that successfully using `nslookup` or `dig` proves almost nothing, and neither does the ability to get an IP from a hostname using `ping`, because the VPC network is designed in a way that happens to make DNS resolution extremely difficult to break.

Comment: TCP traffic was blocked internally, that's why I couldn't do those requests;

Comment: Having the same issue, but cannot understand _TCP traffic was blocked internally_. "Blocked internally" means where: at the unix level? VPC?

Comment: @esteewhy Did you received any e-mails from AWS with the title "Your Amazon EC2 Abuse Report ..." ?

Comment: hey @AndreDurao, i know its an old thread - but is there any chance that u still remember what was the exact problem? what does it mean that your _TCP traffic was blocked internally_?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error is considered to be temporary. I was able to get it to work by running the same command after some time. You could also try to de-associate/associate your elastic IP and rerun the command.

There're some issues posted on [curl repo on github](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/1603) that you might wanna take a look at. Hope it helps!